# Java code taking input is taking a long time to execute

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = input.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
            for(int I = 1; I <= x ; I ++){
                if(x % I ==0){
                sum += I ;
                }
            }
        System.out.println ("The sum of the factors is " + sum);
    }
}
```

The program is supposed to take in a number and print out the sum of its factors. However, it is hanging. I replaced the input code to a simple (int x=10) code and I got the desired answer (18).

Comment: What input number are you trying to test?

Comment: is this the situation metioned when you tried with large number ??

Comment: use a print statement before scanner run time starts on before you input number if you take time delay in inputing a value it is added to runtime  too clearly speaking idle time is also counted as run time once program is made to run .Hope you found my answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

This will never finish executing until you do Ctrl+D, because the input here is `System.in`, which technically doesn't have an end "out-of-the-box":

```
new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it is working. I am not sure what is you input.

i just put additional System out to see remarks

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String [] args){
            System.out.println("Show");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("In:");
            int x = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Out");
            int sum = 0;
                for(int I = 1; I <= x ; I ++){
                    if(x % I ==0){
                    sum += I ;
                    }
                }
            System.out.println ("The sum of the factors is " + sum);
        }
    }
```

and this is the output i got if your input is 12345

```
    Show
    In:
    12345
    Out
    The sum of the factors is 19776
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just made a mistake that I used to always make. When I run my command line programs in Eclipse or whatever, nothing is being printed. I thought, why the F**K are you not running, man? I tried to click the "Run" button for a few times but I still get the same result.

Then I opened up the debugger and stepped through the whole thing and see that it stops on this line:

```
int x = input.nextInt();
```

After that, I realized how stupid am I. The console is waiting for me for the input!

So what is really happening here? When the program runs to the above line, it stops. It waits for you to enter something and press Enter. That's what the `nextInt` method do. In technical terms, this method causes *blocking*.

This is normal, right? The computer, of course, needs to wait for you to enter something before it can go on in a command line program. But because the program didn't output anything before that, you don't realize that the program is already running.

## How to solve this problem

Just enter something in the console and press enter, the program will go on and show the correct output!